# How to use Razor pages in Asp.net Core initially created with Angular CLI?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, asp.net-core, razor

I initially created an ASP.NET Core project using the `dotnet new angular` command in terminal. With this, all the routing is being done by Angular. 
But I want to develop a web application using database and dotnet core authentication. So I think is best to use the cshtml files and import the Angular components I need to use.

With that said, how do I change the page exhibition from Angular components to Razor pages?

Comment: Why do you want to have two different frontend frameworks here? You can easily develop a web app using .net core identity auth with angular on it's own, or even Razor on it's own. I would avoid a hybrid solution.

Comment: @JamieRees I was thinking in dividing the application in asp.net core for the backend and Angular for front-end. It is a personal project and I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but I would like to have authentication, data storage (the reason for the asp.net) and doing it as a SPA (the reason for Angular).

Comment: If you want to use Angular on frontend and .Net backend, then drop Razor. There's no good reason I can think of having two completely different frontend stacks, It will lead to issues.